# Determining the bandwidth of a frequency band in a logarithmic fashion

Tags: java, audio, frequency, frequency-analysis

I'm making a frequency visualizer in Java (& JNI), and have it working so far with linear scales on the X axis (frequency) and Y axis (amplitude). Converting the Y axis into a logarithmic scale was as simple as plotting the log of the amplitude, but I'm having trouble at a conceptual level understanding how I would go about making the X axis scale in a logarithmic fashion (such as on this [tone generator](http://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/)).

Here is my current initialization of each band, where each band represents an equal portion of the total frequencies:

```
    bands = new VisualizerBand[numOfBands];

    float physicalBandWidth = ((float) this.getWidth()) / numOfBands; // So as not to exceed 1 band per pixel
    float frequencyBandWidth = maxFrequency / numOfBands;   // Each band represents an equal percent of the total frequencies represented

    for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++){
        bands[i] = new VisualizerBand();
        ...
        bands[i].setStartFrequency(i * frequencyBandWidth);
        bands[i].setEndFrequency(bands[i].getStartFrequency() + frequencyBandWidth);
        ...
    }
```

From my research and attempts, it seems like the solution will involve deriving each band's frequency bandwidth based on their position in the window, but I'm struggling past that. Any advice, or guidance would be appreciated.